# WinRe.wim what do i do with it?

Tags: wim

I bought a brand new Razer Blade Advanced 2021 and it won't boot.

Razer tech support sent me over a ZIP file (as a link to my email).
After downloading and extracting it, it's a bunch of SWM, WIM files

There is no exe or way to use it.
Their instructions just said to download it. But there is no additional information about it.

[image: Files in Zip]

After copying the files over to the USB drive, the recovery screen says "creating system..." for the last 8 hours

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate the reason you contacted Razer technical support.  All they sent you was a WinRE image.

Comment: @Ramhound they just sent me the WinRE image but I need to recover my computer since it will not boot. I don't know how to do that. The person who has answered pointed me to an article on Razer's website but the directions seem a little incomplete. I've done it and it tells me that it couldn't find the recovery image.

Comment: It's still not clear what problem you are attempting to solve.

Comment: Did you ask Razer tech support how to use the files they sent you?

Comment: Ofcourse I did. Those guys are braindead! They suggested I use a System Restore point to the last time the PC booted to recover my boot loop issue. In my ticket, I told them it's brand new and it wouldnt boot so I have no System Restore points

Answer (score 0):

You use the zip file to create a system recovery stick.

[https://mysupport.razer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2044/~/how-to-create-and-use-a-system-recovery-stick-for-the-razer-blade](https://mysupport.razer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2044/%7E/how-to-create-and-use-a-system-recovery-stick-for-the-razer-blade)

The [Tomahawk instructions](https://mysupport.razer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5313/%7E/how-to-create-and-use-a-system-recovery-stick-for-the-razer-tomahawk-gaming) also show the contents of the file.